# using a variable in the key of APC

Tags: php, apc

I want to do something like this:

> apc_store('apc-$t', $something);

but when looking at the cache it shows "apc-$t". I really tried every possible combination with .'" and other things, but without success. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP won't interpret variables if you use single quotes.  You need to use:

```
apc_store("apc-$t", $something);
```

or:

```
apc_store('apc-'.$t, $something);
```